# Concatenating a single cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm writing a macro to turn a part number from a simple part number to an extended part number. My code right now is not elegant by any means, but it's working.

Say I have a part number A1001 and I need it to become FSAEM–16–121–BR–A0001-AA, where the BR comes from the first 1 and the rest of the part number stays constant, I have this code.

```
Sub Part_Number_Replacer()
With ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B")
.Replace "A100", "FSAEM–16–121–BR–A000", xlPart
.Replace "100", "FSAEM–16–121–BR–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A200", "FSAEM–16–121–EN–A000", xlPart
.Replace "200", "FSAEM–16–121–EN–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A300", "FSAEM–16–121–FR–A000", xlPart
.Replace "300", "FSAEM–16–121–FE–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A400", "FSAEM–16–121–EL–A000", xlPart
.Replace "400", "FSAEM–16–121–EL–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A500", "FSAEM–16–121–MS–A000", xlPart
.Replace "500", "FSAEM–16–121–MS–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A600", "FSAEM–16–121–ST–A000", xlPart
.Replace "600", "FSAEM–16–121–ST–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A700", "FSAEM–16–121–SU–A000", xlPart
.Replace "700", "FSAEM–16–121–SU–0000", xlPart
.Replace "A800", "FSAEM–16–121–WT–A000", xlPart
.Replace "800", "FSAEM–16–121–WT–0000", xlPart
End With
End Sub
```

Told you it wasn't elegant. The part numbers are always in cell B4. How would I go about concatenating the -AA to the end in VBA? I can't find anything about concatenation code. (Right now this macro does everything I need but replace the -AA).

Barring that, is there a more elegant way to write it so I don't need to concatenate the -AA at the end and have it in the same line as the .replace?

Comment: Would a Vlookup work instead?

Comment: the & operator is used in VBA to concatenate 2 strings together.
You say that the number is always in B4 but you are doing a replace on the whole column.  However if the value is indeed in B4 you can do this.

`ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value & "-AA"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below function, which loops through the range and checks for empty cells. Add case statements as needed.  There are better solutions, but this is quick.

```
Sub test()

    ReplaceText (ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").Cells)

End Sub

Function ReplaceText(rng As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        If IsEmpty(r.Value) = False Then
            'r.Value = Replace(r.Value, "as", "bm") & "-AA"
            Select Case r.Value
                Case "A100"
                    r.Value = Replace(r.Value, "A100", "FSAEM–16–121–BR–A000")
                Case "A200"
                    r.Value = Replace(r.Value, "A200", "FSAEM–16–121–EN–A000")
            End Select
            r.Value = r.Value & "-AA"
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @joshski Thanks for accepting the answer.  My vba is rusty, I just realized that didn't need to be a function.  You can replace "Function" with "Sub".

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression might be your only option here since you are searching for a partial match and using composition.

Here is an example replacing all the matching values from column B with the defined templates:

```
' load the data from column B
Dim rg_data As Range, data(), template$, r&
Set rg_data = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
data = rg_data.Value2

' define the pattern to match the targeted values
Const MATCH_PATTERN = "(A?[1-8])(00.)"

' define the replacement templates (key = first group, $2 = second group)
Dim tpls As New collection
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–BR–A0$2-AA", "A1"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–BR–00$2-AA", "1"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–EN–A0$2-AA", "A2"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–EN–00$2-AA", "2"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–FR–A0$2-AA", "A3"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–FE–00$2-AA", "3"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–EL–A0$2-AA", "A4"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–EL–00$2-AA", "4"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–MS–A0$2-AA", "A5"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–MS–00$2-AA", "5"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–ST–A0$2-AA", "A6"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–ST–00$2-AA", "6"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–SU–A0$2-AA", "A7"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–SU–00$2-AA", "7"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–WT–A0$2-AA", "A8"
tpls.Add "FSAEM–16–121–WT–00$2-AA", "8"

' create the regex object
Dim re As Object, match As Object
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.pattern = MATCH_PATTERN

' replace all the values
For r = 1 To UBound(data)
  Set match = re.Execute(data(r, 1))
  If match.count Then  ' if found
    template = tpls(match(0).SubMatches(0))
    data(r, 1) = re.Replace(data(r, 1), template)
  End If
Next

' copy the data back to the sheet
rg_data.Value2 = data
```